# How to change Table Font Size and Color, Php ,Html

Tags: php, html-table

I am trying to increase font size and add a blue background to first cell, but I could not manage it.

```
// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `UserName`,`UserScore` FROM {$table} ORDER BY `UserScore` DESC");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);


echo "<table border='1' align='center'><tr>";
// printing table headers
//for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
//{
  //  $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>Name &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "<td>Score &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>";
//}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)

        echo "<td>$cell</td>";


    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

How can I increase font size and add a blue background to first cell in above table?

Comment: Styling of text, background colors etc. should be done via CSS.  Have you had any experience with CSS before?

Comment: php has nothing to do with it. You'll need CSS, but I don't see any of that. How would you expect this code to do anything with font-size?

Comment: Please start learning CSS. Hardcoded `&nbsp;` and style attributes have been proven a bad practice for the last 10 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this Helps!

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `UserName`,`UserScore` FROM {$table} ORDER BY `UserScore` DESC");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);


echo "<table border='1' align='center'><tr>";
// printing table headers
//for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
//{
  //  $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>Name &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "<td>Score &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>";
//}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    $i = 0;
    foreach($row as $cell)
    {
       if($i == 0)
           $class = "class = 'backg'";
       else
           $class = "class = ''";
        echo "<td ".$class.">$cell</td>";

     $i++;
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Styles here

```
<style>
.backg{background:blue;font-size:18px;}
</style>
```